# Kinect Tracking in C# - Adding more joints to a tracked skeleton

Tags: c#, kinect, tracking, point

Ok here is my situation: I am developing an app that uses the Kinect. I personally still use Windows Vista purely because that is what I am used to and I hate change, but that's besides the point. Anyway I managed to install the Kinect SDK onto Vista by getting a very early beta and hacking the install to not reject my OS.

I am trying to measure head rotation. I cannot use facial tracking as the SDK version I am using does not include it, and upgrading to Windows 7 to install a later version is the last thing I want to do to create one app as I explain above. I also want it to work on Vista, as some people who may want to use it may still be on Vista like myself.

So I was wondering whether it is possible to add more tracking points to a skeleton? Could I add a point on the forehead and the chin and possibly one on each cheekbone? That way I could measure full rotation up to a point that I need.

I this is possible how is it done? If you have any other ideas that will work I would be very grateful if you shared them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I was wondering whether it is possible to add more tracking points to a skeleton?

No.  You can not add a new point to the SDK's tracking algorithm.  It has a preset number of points it knows how to deal with and it is not possible to just add a new point.

> Could I add a point on the forehead and the chin and possibly one on each cheekbone? That way I could measure full rotation up to a point that I need.

You can do this through the face tracking algorithm.  You would obviously need to examine the code very closely and write your own.

Comment: Do you have any links I could follow up and read up on that topic? Because I would have no idea where to start :D

Comment: The face tracking code is available in the v1.6 SDK Toolkit.  I'm unsure if the source is provided external to that. You could try the SDK documentation for some info.